# UITextField in UITableView cell unable to becomeFirstResponder after deleting data

Tags: uitableview

My table view has inline cells adding.

I've got in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    VMEditableTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EditableCell"];
    cell.editableTF.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    cell.editableTF.delegate = self;
    cell.editableTF.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.editableTF setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

    if ([self.extrasArray[indexPath.row] isEqual:@0]) { // recognise new added cell
        self.extrasArray[indexPath.row] = @"";
        [cell.editableTF becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    cell.editableTF.text = self.extrasArray[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
```

When i start table view - inline adding works fine.

The problem starts when i use "clear whole list" button - which simply removes all objects from extrasArray.

When I add cell after clearing it's being dequeued improperly and the textfield doesnt respond to becomeFirstResponder.
(it's not nil, it calls textFieldShouldBeginEditing(always YES) but nothing more happens - no keyboard is showing up.

My last idea was to to override prepareForReuse method inside of Cell Implementation - but sadly neither setting editableTF to nil and reinitalizing it doesnt work.

How can I force cell to recreate itself instead of coping?

Comment: Try to create a cell like this                                  'static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil) 
 {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
 
  // Set up the cell..
  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];  
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
'

Comment: ye - but then textField and imageView in CustomCell would be nil. Instaniating them in init doesn't do the trick also...

Comment: Try to declare textField and imageView out side CustomCell.

Comment: It also creates blank cell. (in debuger they are created - but they dont apper in cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So todays morning was very good for code soultions and finally I came up with one for this problem:

I got rid of storyboard for this cell and changed all pointers of custom cell to strong (so I own them).

Dequeque reusable cell was recreating UITextField from deleted rows making controller confused about ownership and becoming first responder.

be aware that creating them inside of cell init didn't do the trick.

TextField MUST be created and added as subview (also assigned to strong pointer so I get control over it later).

Here is some code:

```
    VMEditableTableViewCell *cell = [[VMEditableTableViewCell alloc] init];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    UIImage *bulletImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"common_ico_dot.png"];
    UIImageView *bulletImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,17,10, 10)];
    bulletImageView.image = bulletImage;

    UIImage *tickImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"common_green_tick.png"];
    UIImageView *tickImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.size.width-30, 17, tickImage.size.width, tickImage.size.height)];
    tickImageView.image = tickImage;
    tickImageView.hidden = YES;

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 10, 227, 30)];
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Maven Pro" size:17.0];
    textField.tag = indexPath.row;
    [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

    [cell addSubview:bulletImageView];
    cell.bulletImageView = bulletImageView;
    [cell addSubview:tickImageView];
    cell.tickImageView = tickImageView;

    if (cell.editableTF == nil) {
        [cell addSubview:textField];
        cell.editableTF = textField;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a cell like this

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    //  Set up the cell..
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];        
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

'

Comment: I use storyboards and iOS6 so no need to do that. Nevertheless doing so (and allocating all subviews in initWithStyle) - creates blank cell.